# Codeigniter:session not working on live website

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, server

I built a website using CodeIgniter. It works fine on localhost, but when I uploaded it on 000webhost it behaves incorrectly. Sessions are not setting .session and not working for live servers.

I called session in the constructor of the controller

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

I am setting its value in the method of the same controller like this

```
$session_array = array(
                'Username'=>'admin', 
                'Logged In'=>'TRUE',
                );
$this->session->set_userdata($session_array);
```

It works to set the value for just one time, but when I click on any other link it expires.

Comment: make sure your controller name starts with capital letter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@navigator Please go to your website setting on **000Webhost** and change the version of PHP to **7.0** it will work fine.